# Custom HTMLs tags firing only in preview/debug mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am having some problems with custom HTML tags in google tag manager. They work only in preview mode and not outside it. A curious detail is that when inside the preview mode "Tags fired on this event" does not show any fired tag. However it fires in Google Analytics. I don't know if this is the reason that it is not being fired outside the preview mode. All tags are published.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you so much.

Below a screenshot of one tag which has this problem:
[tag code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txVzj.png)

I want the tag to be fired when I check one or more checkboxes from the image below:
[place where the tag will be fired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGsWH.png). Actually it is firing only in preview mode on Google Tag Manager.

I expect the tag to be fired in Google Analytics without entering the preview mode in GTM. Actually this is not happening.

Comment: Update with screenshots of your setup

Comment: Hi XTOTHEL, I have updated the question with an image of the tag code and an image of the place where the tag should be fired. If you need anything more please tell me. Thank you very much.